# Error with Stream Framework

Tags: python, stream-framework

I'm trying to setup a basic feed:

```
from stream_framework.feeds.redis import RedisFeed

class PinFeed(RedisFeed):
    key_format = 'feed:normal:%(user_id)s'

class UserPinFeed(PinFeed):
    key_format = 'feed:user:%(user_id)s'


feed = UserPinFeed(13)
```

But when I run `feed[:2]` after adding a single activity, I keep getting this error:

```
<ipython-input-25-41b7cd0d0d8c> in <module>()
----> 1 feed[:2]

/Users/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stream_framework/feeds/base.pyc in __getitem__(self, k)
    303         try:
    304             results = self.get_activity_slice(
--> 305                 start, bound)
    306         except StopIteration:
    307             # There's nothing left, even though the bound is higher.

/Users/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stream_framework/feeds/base.pyc in get_activity_slice(self, start, stop, rehydrate)
    354         print 'line 350'
    355         if self.needs_hydration(activities) and rehydrate:
--> 356             activities = self.hydrate_activities(activities)
    357         return activities
    358

/Users/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stream_framework/feeds/base.pyc in hydrate_activities(self, activities)
    332         activity_data = {a.serialization_id: a for a in activity_list}
    333         print activity_data
--> 334         return [activity.get_hydrated(activity_data) for activity in activities]
    335
    336     def needs_hydration(self, activities):

/Users/home/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/stream_framework/activity.pyc in get_hydrated(self, activities)
     42
     43         '''
---> 44         activity = activities[int(self.serialization_id)]
     45         activity.dehydrated = False
     46         return activity

KeyError: 14929294667170000000001005L
```

I'm able to print out `[<stream_framework.activity.DehydratedActivity object at 0x10e114e90>]` and `[u'14929294667170000000001005']`.

Any clue what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a mismatch of types here, between the Key being shown in the `KeyError` stack trace and the printed representation of `[u'14929294667170000000001005']`

`u'14929294667170000000001005'` is a unicode string
while `14929294667170000000001005L` is a `long` type integer.

Either the Key itself or the value you are attempting to use as the lookup key will have to change so the types are identical. Note that an int with or without the L suffix (signifying the `long` type) will work to retrieve a value from a python `dict`. A simple demonstration:

```
>>> D = {14929294667170000000001005 : 'some value'}
>>> D[14929294667170000000001005]
'some value'
>>> D[14929294667170000000001005L]
'some value'
```

Comment: I'm aware of this, but I'm using a framework so the question is why it's not working in the confines of the framework

Comment: Ah, I see. The bottom response from "tbarbugli" on Jan 13, 2014 in this thread : https://github.com/tschellenbach/Stream-Framework/issues/15 ... mentions that `insert_activity()` is needed to prevent the same error.

Comment: that seems to be the issue, the docs seem to be missing this requirement